# $C$-embedding in uniform spaces

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Every Hausdorff uniform space $X$ has a Hausdorff completion $C_X$. Is it true that $X$ is $C$-embedded in $C_X$? How about the completion with respect to its finest uniformity $\mu_X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. $\Bbb R$ is a Hausdorff completion for $X$. The function
$$f:X\to \Bbb R$$
$$f(x)={1\over x}$$
is continuous. But it cannot be extended to a continuous function on $\Bbb R$. So the uniform space $X$ cannot be [$C$-embedded](http://planetmath.org/cembedding) in any of its Hausdorff completions.

---

Let $(X,\mathcal D)$ be a fine uniform space with a Hausdorff completion 
$(Y,\mathcal E)$. Then any continuous function
$$f:X\to \Bbb R$$
is uniformly continuous. So, [because $\Bbb R$ is complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness), it can be extended to a (uniformly) continuous function:
$$g:Y\to \Bbb  R$$
So $X$ can be $C$-embedded in $Y$.

Comment: I want this answer be deleted.